# How to call the same function for each element in array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I basically have a form where it is passing data from MySQL once the submit button is pressed.

I've got an array retrieved from MySQL and want to call the same function for each element. I have tried a for loop for the last 14 hours and I cannot get it to run the same function for each element in the array.

### form

```
<?php
foreach($pClass->retrieveAllInfo() as $data)
{ 
    echo '
    <form method="post" action"">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_url" value="'.$data['p_Url'].'">'.$data['p_Url'].'
        <input type="hidden" name="post_description" value="'.$data['p_Description'].'">'.$data['p_Description'].'
        <input type="hidden" name="post_image" value="'.$data['p_Image'].'">'.$data['p_Image'].'

        <ul class="items">';?>
        <?php 
            foreach($pClass->retrieveBoards() as $data)
            {
                echo '
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="post_board_id[]" value="'.$data['boardiD'].'">'.$data['boardName'].'</li>
                ';
            }
        ?>
        <?php 
        echo '
        </ul>
        <input name="post_info" type="submit" value="Post">     
    </form>';
?>
```

In the same file, I have the following..

```
if(isset($_POST['post_info']))
{
    pinLogin(); //calls and runs the function

    foreach($_POST['post_board_id'] as $data)
    {
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data); echo '</pre>'; //just retrieving the arrays
    }
}

function pinLogin() // logs into website with headers
{
    $ch         = // ch is a variable from cURL
    $cookie     = '/cookie.txt'; //cookie session
    $url        = 'http://www.website.com/'; // website to post data to

    pinPost($ch, $cookie, $url);
}

function pinPost($ch, $cookie, $url) // posts the information below to the website above
{       
    $boardId    = // here needs to be the board id that needs to be runned for each array..
    $postDesc   = $_POST['post_description'];
    $postUrl    = $_POST['post_url'];
    $postImage  = $_POST['post_image'];

}
```

So basically, when you press the `post_info` button, it runs the `pinLogin()` function, which runs `pinPost()` with the information that is sent from the form, the thing is `$_POST['post_board_id']`; is an array, the `var_dump` results the following:

```
string(18) "136234026166934321"

string(18) "286119451265381250"

string(18) "106468047379795203"

string(18) "468022654964640361"

string(18) "409757334785529893"

string(18) "409757334785575605"

string(18) "490681390589888313"
```

I basically need to post each array as `$boardId` that is inside `pinPost()` and then run the `pinPost()` for all the other arrays. To make it really easy to understand this is exactly what I want to do.

When I click the post button, it will grab the first array `string(18) "136234026166934321"`, submit it to `pinPost()` as `$boardId`, then it will go back to the beginning and run the second array, `string(18) "286119451265381250"` until all arrays have been submited, pretty much it is just posting the same information to different boards, that is exactly what I want to do.

I have tried doing a for loop and running the `pinPost()` inside but I can't pass the board ids to the `pinPost()` function so it does not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try updating your code as follows

```
  /**
   * logs into website with headers
   */
  function pinLogin() {
     $ch = // ch is a variable from cURL
     $cookie = '/cookie.txt'; //cookie session
     $url = 'http://www.website.com/'; // website to post data to


     /**
      * here iterate over all of your board id's and pass them to pin post function. The pinPost function
      * will be run 18 times
      */
     foreach($_POST['post_board_id'] as $boardId) {
        /**
         * @var $boardId string this is the 18 characters long stringg $boardid
         */
        pinPost($ch, $cookie, $url, $boardId);
     }
  }

  /**
   * posts the information below to the logged in website
   *
   * @param $ch
   * @param $cookie
   * @param $url
   * @param $boardId id of the board you want to pin post to (NEW PARAMETER)
   */
  function pinPost($ch, $cookie, $url, $boardId) {
     //$boardId is already here
     $postDesc = $_POST['post_description'];
     $postUrl = $_POST['post_url'];
     $postImage = $_POST['post_image'];

     /* do your stuff here */
  }
```

Comment: I choose your answer because it was much easier to understand and made a lot of sense and also pissed me off a little that I didn't think to run the pinLogin with the board id's, but that is perfect. Thank you for your time, also I'd be pissed if I had wasted more than 14 hours of my life, but I simply learned how to not do it xD

Comment: I chose to do it the way it makes use of your existing _thinking_ and works without radically changing your code. 
And about the _wasted_ time, believe me that time is not wasted. Trying (regardless of success/failure) is an effective way of learning.

Comment: Thomas Edison - I didn't fail. I just found 2,000 ways not to make a lightbulb; I only needed to find one way to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

So you could use a few different techniques to achieve this. My preference would be to use **[array_walk](http://www.php.net/array_walk)** as it's callback accepts both the key and the value of arrays. **[array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)** could be used here as well, though it only ever works with the value of the array in its callback.

```
$postBoards = $_POST['post_board_id'];

function pinLogin() 
{
    $ch         = // ch is a variable from cURL
    $cookie     = '/cookie.txt'; //cookie session
    $url        = 'http://www.website.com/';

    // Run the pinPost callback for each element of $postBoards
    // with your custom user data from this function
    array_walk("pinPost", $postBoards, array($ch, $cookie, $url);
}

function pinPost($boardId, $boardKey, $data)
{
    // You have your boardId for each submitted board available here
    $postDesc   = $_POST['post_description'];
    $postUrl    = $_POST['post_url'];
    $postImage  = $_POST['post_image'];

    // $data contains your pinPost data for example
    $ch = $data[0];
}
```

This makes your `pinPost` function the callback for each element of the `$postBoards` array and will run for each array entry sequentially once you call `pinLogin()`.